# How do I ensure that null fields are not inserted in mongodb collection, from django, using djongo connector?

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I'm sharing a dummy code, expecting myself to be as clear as possible.

**1.** I have a model like this

```
from django.db.models import Model, CharField, IntegerField, DateField

class Account(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    rank = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**2.**  I have my DB settings in django like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'TEST',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

**3.** After running model migration commands, in the django shell, I added two objects(documents) to the configured TEST DB like this

```
In [1]: from dummy.models import Account

In [2]: Account.objects.create(name="Sai")
Out[2]: <Account: Sai>

In [3]: Account.objects.create(name="Ravi", rank=1)
Out[3]: <Account: Ravi>
```

**4.** When I check in Mongodb CLI, I'm getting the null values as well

```
> db.dummy_account.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e4f54939069175d6ed7890e"),
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Sai",
        "rank" : null,
        "date" : null
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e4f54a89069175d6ed7890f"),
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Ravi",
        "rank" : 1,
        "date" : null
}
```

**Q.** (Fields that have null should not be stored) What do I need to do to get my expected result like this?

```
> db.dummy_account.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e4f54939069175d6ed7890e"),
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Sai"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e4f54a89069175d6ed7890f"),
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Ravi",
        "rank" : 1
}
```

Comment: maybe `null=True` in your field definition in the model has something to do with it.

Comment: @RedCricket, I tried taking it off and migrated again, but it doesn't seem to have any effect, this is how it created the collection: `CREATE TABLE "dummy_account" ("id" int32 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" string NOT NULL UNIQUE, "rank" int32 NOT NULL, "date" date NOT NULL);` Even though it's not null, the null fields are being stored

Comment: @KiranRacherla : I'm not quiet sure on djongo but in general on mongo model if you say `required : false` **i.e;** `blank=True` then you would not specify `default=None`, Cause you're saying a field may not be present in request by saying required false, again if you say default that means create a default value if that specific field is not present in request (if `none` resolves to `null` then that's the issue)!! Try removing `default` along with `null`(Even if you purposefully send `NULL`'s to DB - it will throw error, it you'll send NULL's keep it as is) + re-migrate & check..

Comment: @whoami, yep, thanks, I didn't notice this earlier but I tried taking `default=None` off and re-migrated it, but still it is storing the null valued fields. I'm gonna edit my question here

Comment: Also tried with `'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False`, still not getting intended result

Answer (score 0):

Since the model you have created, `Account` has 3 fields, DjAngo will always do an insert of 'rows' (or entries) with rank and date set to `None`. So there is no way of knowing if the user actually set these values to `None`, or they were just not entered.

This is a limitation in DjAngo.